# How to call $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y,Z)$?

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, covariance, joint-distribution, cumulants

Let

$$\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y,Z) = \mathrm E[(X-\mathrm E(X))(Y-\mathrm E(Y))(Z-\mathrm E(Z))]$$

This can be regarded as a generalization of covariance to three random variables.

I am writing a text where I need to use this quantity, but I have not encountered it in the literature, so I'm not sure if there is a standard name for it. Here are some possible names I think I could use:

1. Covariance (can be confused with the normal two-variable covariance).
2. Third-order covariance (not sure about this one).
3. Third-order centered moment (this is accurate, but I'd prefer to find something shorter).

Related: [Covariance for three variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196621/covariance-for-three-variables).

Comment: That's not covariance. It's [coskewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coskewness). It's a 3rd moment. The single random variable concept is skewness.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Thanks, according to that wikipedia page, it can also be called "third cross central moment".

Comment: It is a *third central (multivariate) moment.*